# java - write a gui wrapper around a command line based program

Tags: java, user-interface, command-line

i have a command line based program that i want to write a gui based wrapper for. is there  a way that i can redirect the stdout steam from that program to my gui and launch the other program with arguments?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Invoke the program using `Process` and grab the input / output / error stream of the process.(see an example here: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html)

I am having some problems with formatting, so here are some relevant links:

1. [How to create a process in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006035/how-to-create-a-process-in-java)
2. [Java Process with Input/Output Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream)

Comment: and then look here : http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Answer (score 1):

try [Apache common-exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/), it provides an api to invoke commands and capture the stderr, sdtout and provide an stdin.