# Call class, wait for it to exit, call again

Tags: java, securitymanager, systemexit

I'm working on a program where I want to loop through several config files, and with each file, call a class with that filename as an argument and wait for it to finish.  Currently I am doing:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        String[] a = new String[1];
        a[0] = "data/config" + i + ".xml";
        edu.cwru.sepia.Main2.class.getMethod("main", String[].class).invoke(null, (Object)a);
    }
```

However, what happens is that the class only gets called once, and then the entire program stops.  I think there is an exit line in the class, but since it is a JAR file I can't be sure and I can't edit it.

Let's assume that is the case; how would I get around that to do what I want?  i.e. after the invocation ends with the exiting, my outer loop method continues and just calls the class again with the next argument.

Comment: Spawn the method in separate thread.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy Spawning in a separate Thread will not prevent the obvious call to `System.exit()` in the jar file from terminating the JVM - for all Threads.

Comment: @christianhujer Fair enough. If this jar insists on killing the jvm, you'll have to spawn a new jvm for each invocation. In which case, why not just a bash script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the problem is indeed a `System.exit()` call in the third-party class, you should be able to work around it by following the recommendation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401281/preventing-system-exit-from-api), which provides the following code:

```
  private static class ExitTrappedException extends SecurityException { }

  private static void forbidSystemExitCall() {
    final SecurityManager securityManager = new SecurityManager() {
      public void checkPermission( Permission permission ) {
        if( "exitVM".equals( permission.getName() ) ) {
          throw new ExitTrappedException() ;
        }
      }
    } ;
    System.setSecurityManager( securityManager ) ;
  }

  private static void enableSystemExitCall() {
    System.setSecurityManager( null ) ;
  }
```

However, for your purposes it would likely be a better approach to simply [spawn a separate Java process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006035/how-to-create-a-process-in-java) for the third-party application and wait for it to terminate.  That way you don't have to worry about the third-party code causing side-effects in your JVM instance, or about trying to guess at how to get rid of the side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

I know of two possibilities how to solve this:

- You can install a `SecurityManager` in which you implement the `checkExit()` method before you call this `main()` method. This will prevent the `System.exit()` from actually happening.
- You can run the method in a separate VM, i.e. starting it using one of the `Runtime.exec()` methods.

Both have pros and cons. If the jar files mess around with System properties, you may want to go for a separate VM, if they don't, you may want to go for the SecurityManager as that would be less overhead.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is not from Java but from a shell script (or perl/python/ruby script) and just start the VM multiple times.

You can do this from Java too with `Runtime.exec` or `ProcessBuilder.start`.

It's not easy to *not* stop the JVM when `System.exit()` is called. There is a way to do it though; by installing your own `SecurityManager` with the `System.setSecurityManager` call. You can then override the `canExit` method and throw an Exception (or `Error`) subclass.
However this is not advisable unless you understand the consequences, because it turns on the SecurityManager for the entire JVM which can have unexpected consequences.

Comment: I'd rather work in Python anyway, could you recommend a resource that would show me how to do this?  I would have to make sure that the classpath of whatever I was running included the data folder, did this with a Run Configuration in Java.