# how to create a child process in java?

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

this is my project question and i am trying to solve it can you help me pls...
"There is a computer lab with 3 computers and 1 printer in. There are 8 students and an instructor using the lab. The instructor and the students should be created as the parent and child processes. The children should try to enter the lab to print their homework out. The instructor can allow only 3 students in at the same time, since this is the limit for computer usage."

I am trying to create a parent process and then fork 8 child processes from it, i had created the parent process using java process builder class but i don't know how to create the child processes from it ?help please...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006035/how-to-create-a-process-in-java

Comment: FWIW: Java does not have the idea of 'fork', which is associated with specific behavior.