# How can I turn on screen using Java in Raspberry Pi touch screen?

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am doing a project using Raspberry Pi.

My purpose is to turn on screen using a Java program (by sensor input) when screen state is screensaver.

Is there any function or library in Linux?
If Raspberry's mouse being moved then screen on?

Comment: You can `sudo tvservice -o` (see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22039/turn-on-hdmi-programatically-but-doesnt-turn-on). For how to start a process from Java, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006035/how-to-create-a-process-in-java