# Starting Threads and having background activity

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to have an action (the one in Runnable) that runs in the background even after the app gets killed. I have errors at r in`Thread t = new Thread(r);` (in Thread cannot be applied java Runnable) and at `t.start();`(cannot resolve method)

This is in `onCreate()`

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Alarms", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mh = sharedPref.getInt("morningHour",  hour_x );
        mm = sharedPref.getInt("morningMinute",  minute_x );
        int hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) ;

        if(hours == mh && minutes == mm)
            startAlarm();

        nh = sharedPref.getInt("noonHour",  hour_x );
        nm = sharedPref.getInt("noonMinute",  minute_x );

        if(hours == nh && minutes == nm)
            startAlarm();

        eh = sharedPref.getInt("eveningHour",  hour_x );
        em = sharedPref.getInt("eveningMinute",  minute_x );

        if(hours == eh && minutes == em)
            startAlarm();
    }
};

Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
```

Comment: post the complete java class code

Answer (score 0):

Thread is killed after it's parent process is killed, if you want your thread to keep processing you can start it in a separate process, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2006057/3353241) for more information.

If you need results from your thread try passing information between the two processes, this can be achieved using multiple ways. refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10942526/3353241) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that you could create a thread that is a daemon or not. The daemon thread it is a thread that terminates after the main thread terminates. In your case you need to create a thread that is not a [daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-a-daemon-thread-in-java) thread. You could simply call the method

```
t.setDaemon(false)
```

before starting your thread.

The whole code snippet is:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.onCreate();
}

public void onCreate() {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Alarms", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            mh = sharedPref.getInt("morningHour",  hour_x );
            mm = sharedPref.getInt("morningMinute",  minute_x );
            int hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) ;
            if(hours == mh && minutes == mm)
                startAlarm();

            nh = sharedPref.getInt("noonHour",  hour_x );
            nm = sharedPref.getInt("noonMinute",  minute_x );
            if(hours == nh && minutes == nm)
                startAlarm();

            eh = sharedPref.getInt("eveningHour",  hour_x );
            em = sharedPref.getInt("eveningMinute",  minute_x );
            if(hours == eh && minutes == em)
                startAlarm();
        }
    };

    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.setDaemon(false);
    t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: If he wants to have a background process running, surely he actually wants to have a daemon thread running when the main thread is killed?